# Kendo UI Tooltip display

Tags: kendo-ui

We are using Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC. I've looked at the [docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/allmembers_t_telerik_web_mvc_ui_fluent_charttooltipbuilder.html) and I don't see a method for statically displaying the tooltips upon page load, so that a user is not required to hover over a marker to display the tooltip value.

Is it possible to display the tooltips for a series line upon page load?

Secondly, is it possible to then do so but for only every 4th value, such as shown [here](http://www.telerik.com/clientsfiles/8899416b-9a26-4c0a-a447-e5fd26681e86_chart-w-tooltip.jpg?sfvrsn=0) ?

Comment: you can add labels to your point where you require the tooltip to appear

Comment: Thank you @NitinMall! Being new to Kendo I spent many hours trying to figure this out. For others facing a similar issue, the code provided here [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiple-series-in-kendo-line-chart) got me the final details I needed.   

    `series.Line(model => model.Values).Name("HitCount").Labels(labels => labels.Visible(true).Color("Red")).Color("Blue");`   

Any idea on how to conditionally display the labels?

Comment: I don't think so that you can keep labels conditionally, but a work around is to use label templates and in that you can alter as per the values you get from the data source.